# How to enable default constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, default

I have question.

How to set constructor by default using makefile ?

The code below will cause build error:

```
**no matching function for call to 'TEST::TEST()'**
```

Code:

```
struct TEST{
int a;
int b;

TEST(int aa, int bb) : a(aa), b(bb) {}
};

int main()
{

    TEST a;
    TEST b;

    a = b;

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: The proper place to correct this is in the source code, not in the makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Either add a second (default) constructor ...

```
struct TEST{
int a;
int b;

TEST(int aa, int bb) : a(aa), b(bb) {}

TEST(){} // explicit default
};
```

... or set the default parameters on your current constructor to default values:

```
struct TEST{
int a;
int b;

TEST(int aa = 0, int bb = 0) : a(aa), b(bb) {} // implicit default
};
```